# making scatter plot to draw conclusion with matplotlib. plt (comparison of two factors)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I draw a scatter plot via pandas. and I did the same thing with matplotlib, using the same data but getting two different graphs. the matplot graph has the lowest value of zero and highest of 6 million so it looks very bad, put the pandas graph has 4.9 million till 6 million, so looks much better. why I am getting two different graphs with the same data?
Thanks in advance!

Pandas Code:

```
df_1 = pd.merge(df_forest, df_flood, how='inner')    
sns.regplot(df_1['Forest'],df_1['Flood'])
```

Matplotlib Code:

```
`x = df_forest
 y = df_flood
 plt.title('sssss')
 plt.xlabel("Forest")
 plt.ylabel("Flood")
 matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x,y)
 matplotlib.pyplot.show()`
```

Comment: I would recommend looking at the tutorials on matplotlib's website first. https://matplotlib.org

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:
[image]

Here the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

nx = 100
forest = np.arange(nx) + np.random.randn(nx)
flood = np.arange(nx) + 15*np.random.randn(nx)
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(forest, flood)

plt.figure(figsize=(17,5))
plt.scatter(forest,flood, c=flood, s=300, alpha=0.5,  label='measrued data')
plt.plot(forest, intercept + slope*forest, 'r', label='fitted line')
plt.title('Forest vs. Flood', fontweight = 'bold')
plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

Comment: x = df_forest['Forest']
y = df_CO2['CO2 Emission']
plt.title('CO2 Emission vs Forest Area')
plt.xlabel("Forest Area (sq/km)")
plt.ylabel("CO2 Emission (1000 tonnes)")
N=24
colors=np.random.rand(N)
area=300
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x,y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.4, marker = '$O$')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()

Comment: Great :-). And since you are rather new here: If you find some useful answers here in StackOverflow then you can give an upvote (orange up-arrow on the left of the text field). If you have asked a question yourself and have got an answer, that solves your problem you might click "solved" (= check sign below the up/down arrows, which becomes green) too.